# HTML Tags in AppSource Long Description

Tags: sharepoint-store

I try to figure how to use HTML tags in the long description for an add-in published in the SharePoint appsource.

I see that some descriptions contains sub-title (h1,h3, etc) and link (anchor).

The only example found in the Microsoft's docs is for the bulleted list ([#LI]).

Is [#H1] (for example) a valid tag or [#LI] is the only one accepted?

Edit: i found that html tags are not allowed and the others descriptions i was talking about were for the Microsoft Dynamics apps. SharePoint add-in appsource description accept only plain text.

Comment: If you have found the solution to your question then you can add it in answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html tags are not allowed and the others descriptions i was talking about were for the Microsoft Dynamics apps. SharePoint add-in appsource description accept only plain text.